# Did HTML entities ever work in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, design

It seems that HTML entities such as `&pi;` (π) do not work in comments.  Did they work in comments at some point in the past?

Comment: Have you seen old comments that contain entities? π

Comment: @shog9: I was actually prompted by coming across [my comment here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415/what-property-of-certain-regular-polygons-allows-them-to-be-faces-of-the-platonic/416#416) (second up from the bottom) and thinking that it didn't seem likely I would have left that unedited if the entity hadn't worked at the time.  Did you get that π with an entity or by actually entering the character (which is what I just did)?

Comment: It's possible they were removed then, although I can't recall seeing (nor now find) a bug report on it. I copied the character from your post, as it would *really* suck if comments were stripping Unicode.

Comment: still, while in post I can write &mdash; as many &times as I want, it doesn't work in comments. Which is inconsistent.

Comment: I just ran into this myself. I can use *italic* and **bold** formatting but not HTML entities like &harr;